# Meaning of function with circle and cross

Tags: functions, special-functions

I've seen this function `M2 = tmp ⊕ Pi`. What does the circle with cross do?

Comment: Composition? Unusual notation, but possible . . . Hrm.

Comment: In what context did you see this?

Comment: The article calculated hash functions. tmp is a hash value and Pi is a random secret

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In logic and CompSci, $\oplus$ is used to denote the "***exclusive or***" or "XOR": $\quad x \lor y \land \lnot(x \land y)$.

In set theory, $\oplus$ denotes the ***disjoint union***.

In linear algebra/vector analysis, it's used to denote the ***direct sum*** of two vector spaces.

It's also used to denote ***parity***: see [P Parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_P).

---

Clearly, the context in which it's used is crucial.

---

In $LaTeX$: use `\oplus`.

Answer (score 0):

$\oplus$ is often used for [Directed Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum).

In Computer Science(especially cryptography), $\oplus$ usually means XOR, or bitwise addition.

Comment: Ok I think they meant XOR. Beause the article I read about was about cryptography